# If $a, b, c$ are in geometric progression and $a+b+c=abc$ then what is minimum value of $a^4+a^2+7$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

If $a, b, c$ are in geometric progression and $a+b+c=abc$ then what is minimum value of $a^4+a^2+7$?(a,b,c are positive real numbers)

Comment: Hint: Let $b=ar$ and $c=ar^2$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort. This should be added to the question rather than in the comments.

Comment: Contest question? What's the source, please?

Comment: Are $a, b, c$ integers?

Comment: @MeesdeVries not given, not necessarily

Comment: What about minimum value 7 for $a = b = c = 0$?

Comment: a=b=c=0 gives the minimum (of 7), but it doesn't feel like the answer you're looking for...

Comment: The fact that the solution is trivial (despite your late addition of constraints) makes the problem statement suspicious. Double check it.

Answer (score 4):

Clearly,

$$a^4+a^2+7\ge7$$

and equality is achieved by $a=0$ (which is not allowed).

From the given,

$$a(1+r+r^2)=a^3r^3$$

and for $r\ne0$,

$$a^2=\frac{1+r+r^2}{r^3}$$ so that $a$ can be made a small as you want. There is no minimum, just an infimum.

Comment: You should treat the case $a = 0$ separately, since you need $a\ne0$ in order to get $a^2=\frac{1+r+r^2}{r^3}.$

Comment: @Rchn: right, rewriting. ($a>0$ is given.)

Answer (score 1):

7

When a=b=c=0

At first I thought (and commented, and was ninja'd) that this was a spurious solution. The reason I'm now calling it an answer is that it's also the infimum of all non-degenerate answers.

Let $b=ar$ and $c=ar^2$

The condition is satisfied iff:
$a + ar + ar^2 = a^3r^3$

This gives a cubic in r: $a^2r^3-r^2-r-1=0$

This cubic is -1 at r=0, and is positive in the limit r->infinity, so it must have a positive root. Thus there exists b and c that satisfy this condition for any a. Therefore a can be chosen to be arbitrarily small.

So you can get as close to 7 as you like with "non-degenerate" answers. So either it's the answer or there is no answer.

Comment: See question ,a b c are positive and you are saying a=b=c=0

Comment: Due to Descarte's rule of signs has the equation $a^2r^3-r^2-r-1=0$ exactly one positive root $r.$ However, this root verifies $r>1/a$ from where $b,c>1.$

Comment: There is no need to care about the roots of the cubic, you can work with  $a=f(r)$ rather than $r=f(a)$.

Comment: I know it @Yves. I just wanted to point out the wrong argumentation.

Comment: @user376343: I was addressing Steven.